# Как сместить ссылку "Авторизация" вниз экрана?

Tags: html, css, html5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title> Сайт </title>
        <link href="Main_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <style>
            ::selection {
            color: #1AB2B5; 
            background: rgba( 171, 203, 16, 1.0);}

        </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu_conteiner" class="main">
        <nav id="menu_nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="menu_li"><a href="Main.html" class="menu"> Главная </a></li>
                <li class="menu_li"><a href="menu_2/menu_2.html" class="menu"> Меню_2 </a></li>
                <li class="menu_li"><a href="menu_3/menu_3.html" class="menu"> Меню_3 </a></li>
                <li class="menu_li"><a href="menu_4/menu_4.html" class="menu"> Меню_4 </a></li>
                <li class="menu_li"><a href="menu_5/menu_5.html" class="menu"> Меню_5 </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h1 id="name"> "Название" <h1>
    </div>
    <footer class="Authorization">
        <a id="Authorization1" href="Authorization/Authorization.html"> Авторизация </a>
    </footer>

</body>










</html>
html {
height:100%}
body {
background-image: url(images/Green-blue.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:center;
background-size: 100%;
background-color: #000000;
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
height:100%;}
ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
margin-top: 30px;
text-align: center;
height: 60px;}

.menu {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
color: #ffffff;
padding: 10px;
font-family: Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-transition: all 0.9s 0.09s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.9s 0.09s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0.01s ease;
line-height: 30px;
font-size: 25px;
padding-right: 35px;
padding-left: 35px;}

.menu:hover {
background-color: rgba( 171, 203, 16, 1.0);
border: 3px solid #1AB2B5;
font-size: 27px;}

.menu_li {
display: inline-block;}

#name {
font-family: Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive;
position: absolut;
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 100px;}

.Authorization {
font-family: Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;}

#Authorization1 {
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 40px;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s 0.01s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s 0.01s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0.01s ease;
border-radius: 7px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;}

#Authorization1:hover {
background-color: rgba( 171, 203, 16, 1.0);
border: 3px solid #1AB2B5;
font-size: 45px;}

.main {
 flex-grow:1;}
```